# Why I need add the `Authorization` in the request header when access the APIs?

Tags: javascript, python, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I use the Python/Django write the backend, use Django-Rest-Framework write the APIs, I also used the `rest_auth`, `allauth`, see my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'corsheaders', 

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_docs',  # API docs
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
```

but when the frontend access the APIs, it will must add the `Authorization` in the 
Request Header, otherwise can not access success:
as a example:

```
    var that = this

    // login 
    that.$http.post(Urls.users.login(), params).then((response) => {

      that.$Cookies.set('token', response.data.key);

    }).catch((response) => {   //  if the header do not have `Authorization`, there will go to there directly, and pay attention: the response is undefined.


      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `'rest_framework.authtoken'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and set

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

in settings.py.
Then `DjangoRestFramework` will check you identity when you ask server with unsafe method like `post\patch\delete`.You `login` method is handle by `post` method which will ask identity.But you get your `token` after `login`.

Two way to handle you problem, one is set:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
),
```

which is not recommend.second way is set permissions for your `login` method like:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
@list_route(methods=['POST'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
def login(self, request):
    pass
```

Comment: does the `rest_auth` is a part of `rest_framework` ( part of django-rest-framework )?

Comment: No,it's 3rd party app.